# Object Defined Error in Data from Internet Pull

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out why my code is throwing a 1004 object defined error on the With line. I think I have all of my variables dimmed correctly but I am not sure. This now works for the most part but it is not dumping the correct data after the first X cycle.

```
 Sub Search_People()

Dim Name_Of_Person As String
Dim URL As String
Dim Dashboard_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Dashboard_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim Data_Dump As Worksheet
Set Data_Dump = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataDump")
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Last_Row As Long

Last_Row = Data_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    For X = 1 To Last_Row + 1
        Name_Of_Person = Data_Sheet.Cells(2 + X, 8)
        URL = "URL;" & "https://abc.jiveon.com/people/"
        URL = URL & Name_Of_Person & "%40abc.com"
            With Data_Dump.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            URL, _
            Destination:=Data_Dump.Range("A1"))
             .FieldNames = True
             .RowNumbers = False
             .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
             .PreserveFormatting = True
             .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
             .BackgroundQuery = True
             .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
             .SavePassword = False
             .SaveData = True
             .AdjustColumnWidth = True
             .RefreshPeriod = 0
             .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
             .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
             .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
             .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
             .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
             .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
             .WebDisableRedirections = False
             .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

    Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure the sheet names are correct. I would put a break point on that line ant do a print on each object so see which one is not set to an instace IE in the immediate window type Print Datadump.Name. Good luck

Comment: @AndrewT I tried that but it  gave  me a "Method not valid without suitable object" error. That was for the DataDump variable. I don't know how it could be undefined though.

Comment: The only way is if you have the wrong sheet name like a missing space at the end. Edit the sheet name and copy the Txt.

Comment: @AndrewT I have rewritten the code twice now and checked all of the sheet names and object names but no change. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the URL `QueryTable` connection you need to add `"URL;"` in front of your URL:

```
URL = "URL;" & "https://hgst.jiveon.com/people/"
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx
(search for "URL;" on the page)

Additionally, there are 2 typographical errors in the code:

```
Dim Dashboard_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Dashbord_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
```

Dash**board**_Sheet on the second line (missing `a`).

Then the second one is:

```
.TabelOnlyFromHTML = True
```

Correct syntax: **Tables**OnlyFromHTML

Hope this helps

Comment: That seemed to fix the error that it was throwing. No the issue is that the code isn't doing anything. The data isn't going anywhere. Any thoughts?@ib11

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment. The code literally isn't doing anything though. To my understanding it should be dumping the query in A1 but nothing happens..

Comment: Ok, I googled some more, I think you need to change your code for the Web Query though. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839600.aspx

Comment: I just figured it out and got that part working. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: I think there was something I was missing in the bottom part of the code. I edited it to the above and that issue was resolved.